# Try-Except-Else-Finally return in else alternative?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'm working on a function which can `raise` multiple `Exceptions`. I want to handle these `Exceptions` in their except blocks and then return result with custom message and traceback. The problem is that `finally` is guaranteed so I can't return anything  inside `else` block.

This code works if some `Exception` is raised but it doesn't work if there is no `Exception`. In such case, I want just return `{'success':True}`.

So from this code:

```
def foo():
    try:
        #some code
        return {'success':True}
    except FirstException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was FirstExc'
        return {'success':False,
                'tb':tb,
                'msg':msg}
    except SecondException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was SecondExc'
        return {'success':False,
                'tb':tb,
                'msg':msg}
    ...
```

I want not to repeat `returns`. I tried:

```
def foo():
    try:
        pass
    except FirstException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was FirstExc'
    except SecondException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was SecondExc'
    else:
        return {'success':True}
    finally:
        return {'success':False,
                'tb':tb,
                'msg':msg}
```

Do you know how to do it? I know I could put `return {'success':True}` into `try` block, remove `finally` and `else` blocks and add `return {'success':False,'tb':tb,'msg':msg}` into each `except` block but there are many `except` blocks so the code would be repeated multiple times.

Is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo():
    success = False
    try:
        pass
    except FirstException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was FirstExc'
    except SecondException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was SecondExc'
    else:
        success = True
    finally:
        return {'success':success,
                'tb':tb,
                'msg':msg} if not success else {'success':success}
```

Alternative:

```
def foo():
    result = {"success": False}
    try:
        pass
    except FirstException:
        result['tb'] = traceback.format_exc()
        result['msg'] = 'There was FirstExc'
    except SecondException:
        result['tb'] = traceback.format_exc()
        result['msg'] = 'There was SecondExc'
    else:
        result['success'] = True
    finally:
        return result
```

Slight variation of the above:

```
def foo():
    result = {"success": False}
    try:
        pass
    except FirstException:
        result.update({'tb': traceback.format_exc(), 'msg': 'There was FirstExc'})
    except SecondException:
        result.update({'tb': traceback.format_exc(), 'msg': 'There was SecondExc'})
    else:
        result['success'] = True
    finally:
        return result
```

Comment: The conditional expression makes this rather unreadable. Just use `if not success: return {...}`, then `return {...}` on the next line. No need to use `else:`.

Comment: Will raise a NameError

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: no it won't. If `success` is `True`, the conditional expression won't execute the first part at all. *However*, that is rather hard to see due to the use of the conditional expression on the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a `finally` block. You want to return `False` for exceptions only, `True` otherwise; returning in a `finally` always applies for both cases.

You could either return from both `except` suites, or combine the suites.

Returning from both leads to more repetition:

```
def foo():
    try:
        pass
    except FirstException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was FirstExc'
        return {'success':False,
                'tb':tb,
                'msg':msg}
    except SecondException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was SecondExc'
        return {'success':False,
                'tb':tb,
                'msg':msg}
    else:
        return {'success':True}
```

You can combine the `except` suites into one:

```
def foo():
    try:
        pass
    except (FirstException, SecondException) as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        exception_type = 'FirstExc' if isinstance(e, FirstException) else 'SecondExc'
        msg = 'There was {}'.format(exception_type)
        return {'success':False,
                'tb':tb,
                'msg':msg}
    else:
        return {'success':True}
```

Another option is to build the return value *first*, then add information as needed:

```
def foo():
    result = {'success': True}
    try:
        pass
    except FirstException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was FirstExc'
        result = {'success': False, 'tb': tb, 'msg': msg}
    except SecondException:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        msg = 'There was SecondExc'
        result = {'success': False, 'tb': tb, 'msg': msg}
    finally:
        return result
```

This isn't really all that different from the `return`-from-the-except-suite option however.